Can Pivot Table 'Values' show text?
I have data like below, 'function', 'item' and 'updated part' can have many different values, while 'area' would only have 'app' or 'sp' value.
Data



Function
Item
Area
Updated Part




function a
item 1
app
app1


function a
item 2
sp
sp1


function b
item 3
app
app2


function b
item 4
sp
sp2



I would like to transform / summarize it into below,



Function
Item
app
sp




function a
item 1
app1




item 2

sp1


function b
item 3
app2




item 4

sp2



Is it possible to do it through Pivot table?
I tried but the 'Values' area will always do count / sum function and could not display original text.
===============================================================
Update on 2024-06-04:
For one item, there could be more than one Area & Updated Part.
For example,
Data



Function
Item
Area
Updated Part




function a
item 1
app
app1


function a
item 1
app
app2


function a
item 2
sp
sp1


function b
item 3
app
app2


function b
item 4
sp
sp2



When running the Power Query, there will be an error on the row of "function a",
image1
Expression.Error: There were too many elements in the enumeration to complete the operation.
Details:
    [List]

Does this mean it could not support multi-item? Thank you.
Code used:
    let

//Change next line to reflect actual data source
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],

//set all the column data types to type text
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source, List.Transform(Table.ColumnNames(Source), each {_, type text})),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Changed Type", each [Function] <> null and [Function] <> ""),

//Pivot the "Area" column with no aggregation
    #"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Filtered Rows", List.Distinct(#"Filtered Rows"[Area]), "Area", "Updated Part"),

//to blank repeated functions:
    //add shifted column
    #"Add Shifted function" = Table.FromColumns(
        Table.ToColumns(#"Pivoted Column")
        & {{null} & List.RemoveLastN(#"Pivoted Column"[Function])},
        Table.ColumnNames(#"Pivoted Column") & {"Shifted Function"}),

    //Blank if shifted <> function
    #"Null Repeats" = Table.ReplaceValue(
        #"Add Shifted function",
        each [Function],
        each [Shifted Function],
        (x,y,z) as nullable text => if y <> z then y else null,
        {"Function"}),
        
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Null Repeats",{"Shifted Function"})

in
    #"Removed Columns"


Several functions can deal with, or return, text like vlookup() or if(). Try "=if(A1=1,"yes","no")" in cell B1.

It's not clear what 'app or sp value' means. Is it always 'App', or is it 'App1, App2, App3, ...'? You can do this by transforming your data, but perhaps not directly.

You will need to create a measure to do this:

enter the formula
=CONCATENATEX(Table2,Table2[app],";")


Now add the new measute "appt" to your Pibot Values


Power Query, available in Windows Excel 2010+ and Microsoft 365 (Windows or Mac) can pivot data with no aggregation, allowing text results.
To use Power Query

Select some cell in your Data Table
Data => Get&Transform => from Table/Range
When the PQ Editor opens: Home => Advanced Editor
Make note of the Table Name in Line 2
Paste the M Code below in place of what you see
Change the Table name in line 2 back to what was generated originally.
Read the comments and explore the Applied Steps to understand the algorithm

It is basically three steps of code:
let

//Change next line to reflect actual data source
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table2"]}[Content],

//set all the column data types to type text
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source, List.Transform(Table.ColumnNames(Source), each {_, type text})),

//Pivot the "Area" column with no aggregation
    #"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Changed Type", List.Distinct(#"Changed Type"[Area]), "Area", "Updated Part")
in
    #"Pivoted Column"


If you want to "blank" the repeated Function cells, you can use conditional formatting, or you can add a few lines of M-Code in Power Query:
let

//Change next line to reflect actual data source
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table2"]}[Content],

//set all the column data types to type text
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source, List.Transform(Table.ColumnNames(Source), each {_, type text})),

//Pivot the "Area" column with no aggregation
    #"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Changed Type", List.Distinct(#"Changed Type"[Area]), "Area", "Updated Part"),

//to blank repeated functions:
    //add shifted column
    #"Add Shifted function" = Table.FromColumns(
        Table.ToColumns(#"Pivoted Column")
        & {{null} & List.RemoveLastN(#"Pivoted Column"[Function])},
        Table.ColumnNames(#"Pivoted Column") & {"Shifted Function"}),

    //Blank if shifted <> function
    #"Null Repeats" = Table.ReplaceValue(
        #"Add Shifted function",
        each [Function],
        each [Shifted Function],
        (x,y,z) as nullable text => if y <> z then y else null,
        {"Function"}),
        
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Null Repeats",{"Shifted Function"})

in
    #"Removed Columns"


Edit for multiple entries for each item
Add Custom Function
//credit: Cam Wallace  https://www.dingbatdata.com/2018/03/08/non-aggregate-pivot-with-multiple-rows-in-powerquery/

//Rename:  fnPivotNoAggregation

(Source as table,
    ColToPivot as text,
    ColForValues as text)=> 

let
     PivotColNames = List.Buffer(List.Distinct(Table.Column(Source,ColToPivot))),
     #"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(Source, PivotColNames, ColToPivot, ColForValues, each _),
 
    TableFromRecordOfLists = (rec as record, fieldnames as list) =>
    
    let
        PartialRecord = Record.SelectFields(rec,fieldnames),
        RecordToList = Record.ToList(PartialRecord),
        Table = Table.FromColumns(RecordToList,fieldnames)
    in
        Table,
 
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Pivoted Column", "Values", each TableFromRecordOfLists(_,PivotColNames)),
    #"Removed Other Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom",PivotColNames),
    #"Expanded Values" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Removed Other Columns", "Values", PivotColNames)
in
    #"Expanded Values"

Use it like this:
let

//Change next line to reflect actual data source
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table3"]}[Content],

//set all the column data types to type text
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source, List.Transform(Table.ColumnNames(Source), each {_, type text})),

//Pivot with no aggregation
    Pivot = fnPivotNoAggregation(#"Changed Type","Area","Updated Part"),
    //to blank repeated functions:
    //add shifted column
    #"Add Shifted function" = Table.FromColumns(
        Table.ToColumns(Pivot)
        & {{null} & List.RemoveLastN(Pivot[Function])},
        Table.ColumnNames(Pivot) & {"Shifted Function"}),

    //Blank if shifted <> function
    #"Null Repeats" = Table.ReplaceValue(
        #"Add Shifted function",
        each [Function],
        each [Shifted Function],
        (x,y,z) as nullable text => if y <> z then y else null,
        {"Function"}),
        
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Null Repeats",{"Shifted Function"})

in
    #"Removed Columns"


Hello, thank you, this works. But I have updates on the data. When there is more than one Area & Updated Part for a Function & Item, the Area and Updated Part become empty. Is it possible to show more than one Area & Updated Part ?

Updates: I found that I could solve this issue by adding Index column. Is this the best solution?

@AngelLee Depending on the nature of your repeats, that may work well. A more generalized solution would be a custom function and I have edited my answer to show that. See which works better on your actual data.

You can do this in a pivot table, but like lots of tricky pivots, you would need to transform your data first (into a numeric option).
In this case, App/SP sounds like a category, so we put that into the pivot column, and we create a new variable 'App/SP Value' to use as the value. However, this may or may not work; it depends on whether there are duplicate entries. This is unclear from your data example.

